# Am I transgressing by accepting evolution?

Tags: evolution

A very hotly-debated this question is, on this site. But before I begin I must clarify:
**I am not specifically referring to human evolution** (since it's contradicting all the Quranic interpretations hitherto, or as it appears on other questions, I do not stand for it)

Now. I got this thought while I was marvelling at the diversity of life Allah has created on this land. Yes, I accept evolution. And it's not by any choice but by virtue of evidence. There is ample proof that organisms of all kinds change over time, randomly. Take the Flu virus - every year we need a new flu vax since the flu virus eventually evolves to circumvent the vaccine's action.
Another evidence would be "atavism" (reappearance of ancestral parts/features in modern species; you can find examples online).

At least, microevolution (changes in genetic information over time) is 100% known to be correct.

I have a point that I'd like to put in response to certain answers to other similar questions. God forgive me do I sound like a blasphemer:

- Some people wrote about the instantaneity in creation of anything that Allah wills. And they use this as an argument against evolution of organisms --- But Allah SWT Himself clearly states that the Earth and the Heavens were created in a period of 6 days (not necessarily Earth days). Not instantaneously. Could such thinking then not be extended to the creation of life?